# Lots of duplicate answers on a question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, popularity

This question seems to have about 10 answers that are duplicates of the accepted answer or of another answer, most of which are one line of code answers that don't add anything new:

[How to convert byte[] to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003275/converting-byte-to-string-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

Of course most of them were answered at the same time, so that explains why it happened, but shouldn't they be cleaned up now?

Edit:
Note that not all of the answers are exact duplicates of the accepted answer. 3 of the answers use this:

System.Text.Encoding.Default

and most of the other answers use this:

System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

but since this post was created, a lot of the answers have been heavily down voted, resulting in the three answers using "Encoding.Default" all having negative votes, even though only two of them are duplicates of the one posted in January.

Comment: see [Lots of not-always-useful but well-intentioned answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166566/165773) and [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168)

Comment: That is a strain of what is known as: rep whoring. You will get this with a lot of basic questions, it can get really stupid at times.

Comment: The productive thing you can do in a case where there are a lot of very short and almost identical answers is to write a better answer. Compare multiple options in your answer if there are alternatives (e.g. in this example, explain the difference between using `Default` and `UTF8`). Or at least explain the solution, instead of only typing one line of code. For the question you linked, somebody did exactly that more than 4 years later, and got a good number of upvotes.

Comment: Why has Robert Harvey gone into that post and deleted several answers 5 years on? And kept one that was edited to its final form in 2013.

Comment: @CashCow as far as I can tell, he did this following the [guidance given by Jeff Atwood for this kind of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773 "How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?")

Comment: Isn't "combining answers" meant for community wiki where the answer given is by several contributors? That could have been done in this case.

Comment: @CashCow what you call "combining" looks like [minor cosmetics](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1003289/revisions) to me. If "Timbo's answer" was posted after accepted one, it's removal looks sensible: per my reading, it should have been an edit or comment to the edited answer

Comment: Looks like they were both posted together, the accepted one got more upvotes but Timbo got 18, then the accepted one was later edited by someone else to match Timbo's one which is strange given it had got more upvotes and been accepted.

In any case letting the one answer be credited to both is kinder than deleting Timbo's.

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [How to deal with duplicate answers posted long after first answer(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171221/165773)

Answer (score 17):

No the answers should not be "cleaned up" as long as they were all added at around the same time.

If a new answer is added which duplicates an existing, old answer then that should be considered for deletion as it doesn't add anything to the sum of human knowledge.

Comment: "it doesn't add anything to the sum of human knowledge" why wouldn't that apply to answers posted at the same time?

Comment: @RyanDansie - I suppose it doesn't, but because they were posted at around the same time when the question was first asked the benefits of deletion don't really outweigh the costs of doing the deletion.

Comment: given that [question in question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1003275/839601) has *200K+ views*, classical Atwood's guidance may apply: [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: @SList: It might make the best answer float to the top (if it gets comparable scrutiny to the higher-voted ones at least), but the long tail makes it difficult for a new (and perhaps better) answer to **get noted at all**. Also, you are basically arguing that ***reading-time is extremely cheap or free***. Also, many of those answers are without possibility of error redundant, as they are *exact duplicates* (Just like the asker I dismiss the possibility of plagiarism there though).

Comment: @Deduplicator good observation about _reading-time_. Wonder how much reading time did it cost to read 10 repetitive answers for 200,000 site visitors who viewed the question

Comment: @SList: The same answer posted at least 5 times is redundant. This isn't about a question worded slightly different with different answers.

Comment: @ChrisF: Some of the answers were added this year and are duplicates.

Comment: @staticx after [your comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271158/lots-of-duplicate-answers-on-a-question/271159#comment93333_271159), I searched through answers for occurrences of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString`. That was... some kind of fun

Comment: @gnat: 698?! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Comment: @staticx no just five, I searched only answers in this question. :) It helps to think that for casual google visitors most of the garbage is somewhat [hidden under the default answers sort by votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions/238443#comment781462_238443 "explained in more details here") but even to them this may look not quite okay, I tested in default sort and dirty laundry remains quite visible

Comment: So we've voted "no" on a 16-6 majority but Robert Harvey goes in and starts deleting them anyway?

Comment: @CashCow - well if the question/answers were flagged and Robert didn't see this question then I can see how this would happen. Different mods can have different interpretations on things ;)

Comment: He did see this in meta though given he edited it 12 hours ago

Comment: @CashCow - I meant that he might have seen flags on the question/answers dealt with them *then* saw this question. At which time there was little point in reversing his decision.

Comment: @SList: "The 5 answers all have the same content, but even small differences in phrasing or naming can make a difference to how they are understood". Baloney.

Comment: @SList: You can't sit here and tell me that those answers helped anyone. That's why I said Baloney. It's not rude.

Comment: @SList: Nobody who downvoted the deleted answers that use `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);` explained why, so the answers don't impart any useful information.  If System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result); should not be used, edit that information into the remaining answer with an explanation.  Your "Not an Answer" flags are still invalid.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no sense of writing same answers again and again unless you have something meaningful to add to it.

So, yes they should be deleted if they are exactly same (I think). But that would be **much more** workload on the moderators of the site, as the community is so large it would be difficult to stop maximum users from doing that.

Comment: Actually, the OP picked one of the really popular questions. Perhaps check this answer from Jeff: [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069)

Comment: Why should they be deleted? If you look at the answer's, all of them have +ve response from community (I mean +1) even if they are duplicates.

Comment: Even if they are +1'd, there is no sense at all of writing the same thing again. And I guess, maybe, to increase their reputation points many users vote up or give duplicate answers. I've seen that.

Answer (score 2):

I think, according to the guidelines, if the question has turned out to be "popular", then it is possible to make this into a "community wiki" type of question.

It is possible to make the answer attributed to more than one contributor, and in the case actually posted, I think it qualified for this to be done.

That way you simply show the "answer" as contributed by several posters (all 8 or whatever of them) and doesn't "offend" any of them that their answer was "deleted" (when it was genuinely posted within a minute of the other one).

Site integrity maintained, answer well-established, nobody offended. What could possibly go wrong?

Well ok, so if the question isn't popular and it happens? In particular a "new" question? Well maybe after a day or two the answers can still be combined by a mod. I have no idea what happens to reputation if there are new upvotes but the site owners can decide about rep. (I would suggest that, once a post is combined, upvotes give 1 to each contributor if there are 6 or more of them, 2 if there are 4 or 5, 3 if there are 3, 5 each if there are 2 of them).

All this is still better than keeping one answer and deleting the other(s).

This should be done based on flags. You can't expect the moderators to run around looking for these.

By the way, if it isn't possible to combine answers in general now, it should be made possible then done.

To summarize in general:

- If multiple posters have contributed the same answer at the same time, merge them into one answer with all of these posters jointly credited. This both maintains the **integrity** of the site, and the **history**, i.e. that the answer was submitted simultaneously by all these posters not just one of them, and is less likely to cause offense.

Comment: If I might summarize: Be fair to the contributors, the sites quality is a secondary consideration? Or is that too pointed?

Comment: @Deduplicator : do you mean duplicate answers improve the site quality ?  (Note that from your nickname I wouldn't expect you to…)