# When recommending for deletion because of a low-content-but-factually-correct answer, which option should I use?

Tags: discussion

What's the correct close option for somebody just dumping some (presumably correct) code into their answer?  I'm talking about inside the moderation queue for answers flagged low-quality.

Comment: The correct moderation-option is downvoting, as far as I know. Anyway, have not succeeded in closing an answer yet ;-)

Comment: Some of my highest scoring posts are "code dumps".  Click the Skip button if you don't know if the code correctly solves the OP's problem.  If you do know then you don't have to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

Downvote, if you think the answer warrants it.

You can't close answers, and factually correct answers have no justification for deletion.

Comment: _"factually correct answers have no justification for deletion"_ -- [look who's talking](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/839601 "status-completed, dozen answers annihilated, 10Kers can see what happened there")

Comment: As a general rule, this is absolutely correct. Lack of text accompanying code is not grounds for deletion by itself - particularly for reviewers. Additional factors (explosion of redundant answers, very late answers that duplicate existing answers) can be grounds for diamond-mod cleanup.

Comment: @gnat: The OP never mentioned anything about answer duplication.

Comment: yes, and that's exactly their fault. As opposed to moderators, LQ reviewers don't deal with hundreds troublesome posts a day. Review limit is mere 20, this makes it totally possible to just open it in a separate browser window and carefully study everything about it. What was the question, what were other answers, what were comments. If this sounds like too much work, one would better [Skip](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601 "There is no shame in using “Skip”") and let others handle it, there are ~30,000 users who can review in LQ queue