# Large Number of Valid Answers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, specific-question

I just had a review (in the Late Answer queue, not VLQ) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280394/2499035), and wasn't sure how to respond to it. For all I know it's perfectly accurate, and the question doesn't really require a long response in order to answer it. But it doesn't seem like it could be very useful, given the massive number of other answers which are all saying different things.

The question,

> How do we change [the android] emulator screen orientation to landscape or portrait?

Has the following answers:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f12</kbd>
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>f12</kbd>
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f11</kbd>
4. <kbd>numpad 7</kbd>
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>f11</kbd>
6. <kbd>left ctrl</kbd><kbd>f11</kbd>
7. <kbd>numpad 9</kbd>
8. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f12</kbd><kbd>f12</kbd>
9. <kbd>f9</kbd>
10. <kbd>f7</kbd>
11. <kbd>left ctrl</kbd><kbd>f12</kbd>
12. <kbd>left ctrl</kbd><kbd>windows key</kbd><kbd>f11</kbd>

These answers are all for different operating systems and models of computer, so while the question itself might not be too localized, the answers seem like they are. Combined with the fact that there's a lot of noise in the answers (people saying what didn't work for them, giving over key combinations, etc.), it seems to me like the answers are hard enough to navigate that they aren't providing a useful resource.

So my questions are, 1) What should I have done in the audit of that answer, and 2) Should anything be done about the question itself or its answers?

Comment: question in question has 60K+ views, that reminds a recently discussed issue with a similar (high-views) question: [Lots of duplicate answers on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/839601)...

Comment: ...bringing your concern to meta looks like a right thing to do in cases like this. Hopefully followed by moderators invoking [Atwood's magic cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: @gnat The directions in that post for cleaning up answers (merge, but don't just make a massive list) seem like they suggest merging the answers, but exclude the only way to do it in this case. The only pros/cons of one way over another is which one happens to work on the users specific configuration. The sum of the answers is just a list of possible answers.

Comment: my reading of the directions there is they seem to give significant freedom for moderators to pick what to do but also explain what approaches to avoid. It's rather general and not very prohibitive, and main point seems to be that high-view questions deserve _individual_, careful treatment (side note one bad thing about your question here is that it cost me 7 rep in voting down obviously blatant garbage there:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to delete the answer in question for any of the reasons available in the VLQ queue.  From the queue's perspective you should mark it as okay.  If you personally think that the answer isn't helpful, then you can downvote it.

As for the question, it would appear that, due to a lack of context supplied in the question, there is simply too much information to adequately answer it, since the answer to the question is wildly dependent on context/environment, and the answers will simply vary widely based on said context.  It seems reasonable to consider such a question "too broad", and for the question to be required to specify enough context for the scope of the answers to be more reasonable.

Comment: worth noting that [comment under the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-to-change-screen-orientation-in-android-emulator/26280394#comment26408011_1991318) suggests that it's a duplicate... of a yet another high-view (100+K) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618967/switching-to-landscape-mode-in-android-emulator), which seems to be also polluted with repetitive "answers"

Comment: So is the correct response to flag the question and let the moderators deal with it?

Comment: @resueman You can simply flag for closure; that does not require moderator intervention.