# How is the "times a developer found your solutions here" figure calculated?

Tags: support, 10m-questions-milestone

Congrats SO on reaching 10M questions! (Next up: 10M *answered* questions.) On the https://stackoverflow.com/10m page, how is the staggering 7,522,902,979 "times a developer found your solutions here" figure calculated?

Comment: If _People Reached_ is any indication, they just made it up... with missing data, a convoluted algorithm, and some arcane hand-waving. :P

Answer (score 25):

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/352972/test) in SEDE (that doesn't include deleted questions) the total number of views is 14,932,504,077. The data was last updated Sunday, so there is about 4 days of views that would need to be added to it.

Taking 14,932,504,077 DIVIDED BY 2 , gives us 7,466,252,038.5

So I'd say they just took the total sum views of all non-deleted questions (including since last update of SEDE) and Divided by 2 to get the number.

If that's not what they did, well, the results are amazingly the same as whatever method they used.

Comment: They should have divided by 100 instead of 2, for a more realistic figure.

Comment: To be fair @NormalHuman, it says "times a developer found your solutions here", not "times a developer found your solutions here *helpful*" nor "times a developer found *their needed* solutions here"

Comment: @NormalHuman [example with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/839601) suggests that dividing by 5 would make sense

Comment: That is an excellent bit of reasoned guesswork, nice one. I was thinking views as well, but I would definitely have divided by a larger number. I'm hoping for an "official" answer, but I think your reasoning is quite sound indeed. As you say, the figure correspondence is *astonishing* otherwise. The 10m figure divided by your figure above is 1.007587600942437, and as you say, it's been a few days since that data was refreshed.

Comment: @NormalHuman I agree, there's no way every second view is a solution. I'd wager to say most views are by people looking to answer the question.

Comment: @Rob You'd lose that wager; most views are by people who don't have and won't have a Stack Overflow account; in particular, they never post.

Comment: 11 significant digits... Are you sure this is warranted (given uncertainties in timing, etc.)?

Comment: You mean, 7,522,902,979 didn't find _my_ solution helpful?

Comment: How many upvotes on answers?

Comment: I used the site for 6 months before I joined and I would put the number, from personal experience, at somewhere between 1 in 10 to 1 in 20 but certainly not 1 in 2.

Comment: @jakekimds: It's a good thought, but even *that* would be suspect: I often upvote good answers that didn't actually help *me*, as long as I know they're correct. In fact, I'd say the number of total answer upvotes I've given is wildly, wildly higher (like, orders of magnitude higher) than ones that have helped me *personally*. I will grant I'm probably not a typical SO user.